# Scalable way to report on business hours for standard and custom objects

Tags: reporting, service-cloud-console, casemilestone, service

Hello fellow trailblazers! I am currently stuck with a requirement to create reports on how much time a case/work order and custom object spent on a particular status in business hours. Our initial solution would be to create formula fields to calculate time spent per status but I feel this could be a lot more scalable. Does anyone have any ideas on how to report on business hours without creating any extra fields?

Comment: Have you looked at [Entitlements and Milestones](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.entitlements_parent_admin.htm&type=5)? I think this might be the solution you're looking for.